# Reference group variable in Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, devops, pipeline

I tried to find online, but all the options I tried are not working for me.

I have an Azure pipeline that runs a Python script, and inside of it I need to fetch a group variable value, this variable contains the banckend Url. I tried multiple ways, but still not working. Could anyone shed a light here?

[image]

This is the way I am trying to add the value with $(ENVIRONMENT), but I also tried $(env:ENVIRONMENT), $(Environment), $(env:Environment).

Thank you in advace.

Answer (score 1):

On this Azure Pipelines page, you'll see a TAB called Variables. Click in this tab, select Variables Group and then Link Variable Group. In this way, you can select what variable group you'll use.

To use a variable from a variable group, you need to reference a key from the variable group, for example:

Example of variable group Development with the key/values:

```
- name: URL
  value: http://localhost
- name: ENVIRONMENT
  value: DEV
```

In your pipeline:

```
 echo $(URL)
 echo $(ENVIRONMENT)
```

Using the Python task:

```
import os

URL = os.environ.get('URL')
print (URL)
```

I recommend you change this pipeline from the Classic mode to Yaml mode; the pipeline will be more modular and reusable.

Microsoft doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops-2022&tabs=yaml